# Can't set AlarmManager to repeating one

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to set an Alarm to wakes up every 30s but it doesn't work. It does just 1 time at the beginning. I'm not sure if i've to use setInexactRepeating or setRepeating or setExact(and recall the method); and if i should use **ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP** or **RTC_WAKEUP**.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    alarmMethod(this);
}

public static void alarmMethod(Context context) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, LocalWordService.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0 ,myIntent, 0);

    Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());//set the current time and date for this calendar

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();        

    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);        

    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 30, pendingIntent);
    Log.d("MainActivity", "Alarm at = " + cal.getTime().toString());
    Toast.makeText(context, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

And my Service is:

```
public class LocalWordService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onBind", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WAKE UP!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("Service", "ActualTime : " + DateFormat.getDateInstance().getCalendar().getTime().toString());
    //MainActivity.alarmMethod(getApplicationContext());
}
```

}

PS: I'm testing with an Android Lollipop device. (5.0.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> put your code from `onCreate()` to `onStartCommand()`

because I think you are using `startService()` in `onReceive()` of your alarm receiver. and first time it create your service and call `onCreate()` but after 30 seconds when `startService()` get called then service is already created and hence it call `onStartCommand()`.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WAKE UP!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("Service", "ActualTime : " + DateFormat.getDateInstance().getCalendar().getTime().toString());
    //MainActivity.alarmMethod(getApplicationContext());
    return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
}
```